# How to assign a fixed UUID value in RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, uuid, rdd

In a spark program I first initialised 2 RDDs and then used the 2nd RDD in a while loop as follows:

```
var nodes = sc.parallelize(ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
var node_GroupIDs = nodes.map(x=>(x, UUID.randomUUID()))
var i = 0

while (i < 10) {
    node_GroupIDs.foreach(println)
    i += 1
}
```

I found in different iterations for a certain node ID the corresponding group ID has different value. It seems that in each iteration the RDD had been initialized again. 
How to assign a fixed UUID value to a node in this case?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to cache the RDD in order to have always the same result. Indeed, what is happening is that the RDD is recomputed each time there is an *action* on it: i.e. each time you call the `foreach` method, every step is recomputed from scratch, both the `parallelize` and the `map`.

If you `cache` the RDD after the `map`, instead, it is computed once, the first time you invoke the `foreach` action. Then the result is saved in memory and the other `foreach` actions will read the result cached in memory and you will get always the same results.

As pointed out by @David Griffin, this wouldn't solve the issue if an executor crashes. In order to cover this case, it is necessary to `checkpoint` it, after having cached it (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8582).

Thus, the proper way to solve the issue should be:

```
node_GroupIDs.cache()
node_GroupIDs.checkpoint()
```

Comment: If you cache it, isn't it still possible it gets recomputed, say if you lose an executor?

Comment: caching the RDD doesn't seem the best option. @DavidGriffin is right. If you loose an executor the map will be re-executed and a new UUID will be generate. Still is not clear to me why do you want to have 10 RDDs with the same UUID printed. I suppose this is part of a bigger piece of code. Can you explain what is your purpose?

Comment: Yes you're right, but I think that this was useful only for a test, since the source is the `parallelize` function. Using `checkpoint` or writing it to a directory, then reading it again would be the best option in a real context...but this is not the case up to me

Comment: I want to implement a single linkage clustering with spark. First I need to assign each node a group ID. When initializing the RDD the 10 entries have 10 different UUIDs and it's OK. But in while loop the corresponding UUIDs change in every iteration so that I can't retrieve the group ID in the next iteration.

Comment: I updated the answer with the suggestion by @David Griffin